# How to find out in source code the function names the Xcode's otool outputs for you?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, security, otool

I have supposedly 2 security vulnerabilities in the iOS app I developed. This [medium article](https://medium.com/cybersecurityservices/analyzing-the-ipa-file-of-an-ios-based-application-9c0a1749fe69) enlisted both issues I faced.

Look for:

> Usage of Insecure Random Number Generator

and

> Usage of Banned/Deprecated APIs

Those are the two issues I faced in my iOS app as well. I used Xcode's and ran the terminal command like shown in the link above and saw that these deprecated methods like `_random` and insecure methods like `_memcpy` and `_strlen` are being used in the app.

What I want to do here is to understand where in my source code I am using these methods. I have searched my entire source code of my Xcode Project, I don't have it used or called directly.

> otool outputs in assembly language format and shows random address

How can I find out in source code where I must be using these methods? or decipher the assembly code to ObjC source code? so that I can remove that code and use a better alternative which in turn will remove the security vulnerability.

Comment: Try to add a symbolic breakpoint on _random and debug your program. You may find which of your method is calling it through other library call.

Comment: Try to open the DerivedData dir of the app, and grep it for those. It should find some symbols.

Comment: You found answer to this. Even I am trying to solve similar issue.